# Required Driver for Discrete: AMD Radeon R7 M340 (2 GB DDR3 dedicated, switchable) Ubuntuu 14.04.1

Tags: graphics

I want to install driver for Integrated Intel HD Graphics 510: Intel HD Graphics 520 Discrete: AMD Radeon R7 M340 (2 GB DDR3 dedicated, switchable) HD audio with DTS Studio sound Intel Dual Bands Wireless - 3165 802.11 a/b/g/a/ac 1x1 Wifi and Bluetooth  4.0 Combo for Ubuntu 14.04.1 in Hp Pro 450 G3

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're asking? Your title asks for only one thing, but then you add several other things, two of which doesn't make sense together (HD Graphics 510 and HD Graphics 520 aren't generally both in one system).

Comment: Integrated Intel HD Graphics 520 and Discrete AMD Radeon R7 M340 (2GB DDR3 dedicated, switchable)